# Upgrading the app version registered with task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

The only way to upgrade the version is to use the SCDF shell.
Is there any way we can integrate with CI tools like Bamboo.
Or
Is there a way we can use the K8s pods in registering the task and not the jar files

Answer (score 1):

> The only way to upgrade the version is to use the SCDF shell.

This is one of the ways the SCDF REST client (in this case the SCDF shell) can access the SCDF server to upgrade the version (force register the `task` application).

If you want your CI tool to register your `task` application, you can still call the [REST endpoint for the AppRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-registered-applications) via HTTP request to force register the app as soon as you have the new artifact is available for the upgrade.

As a side note, you can use [Spring Cloud Skipper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-skipper) for app registration with versioning and control the lifecycle operations (deploy, upgrade, rollback, delete) from SCDF. But, currently, this feature is supported only for `Stream` applications not for `task` applications.

Not sure what you meant by using k8s pods for registration. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In our current flow, the spring boot app (containing spring batch job) is deployed to  kubernetes as a POD and it runs as a cron job.

Comment: Are you using Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for Kubernetes in this case? If so, you will have the same REST endpoints accessible to register the `task` application as mentioned above.

Comment: But to register a task we need a artificat. A jar with version. Can it be a POD instead of an artifact/jar?